# What are all the new detector units in HoTS?

Tags: starcraft-2

... and how do they change tactics when using cloaked units?

I'm particularly interested in how they'd change the [3-Gate Dark Templar](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/3-Gate_Dark_Templar_(PvT)) build.
I used to have quite a lot of fun with this build in WOL, would it still be viable? Or the new detector units will make this build obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no new *pure* detector units in Heart of the Swarm.

However, the Protoss Oracle can temporarily gain the ability to detect via its "Envision" ability (this lasts 60 seconds, and costs only 50 energy).

The main thing to watch out for, then, is that a protoss opponent without a robotics facility can still field detectors if they have a stargate.

Comment: Is envision still in the game? http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/oracle

Comment: @Resorath It got moved from the mothership core. http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/mothership-core

Comment: The battle.net pages are quite out of date, currently.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle can detect with an ability. Other than that, I'm pretty sure the new units do not have detection.

EDIT:
http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Oracle
envision detects cloaked units.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Oracle) has the ability Envision, that makes it a detector for 60 seconds. So, you can no longer assume a Protoss player does not have detection if they don't build a Robotics Facility.

The Zerg Spore Crawler no longer needs an Evolution Chamber to be built, so a Zerg player can set detection up earlier.

As far as I can tell, no detection change has been made for Terrans.